# Не могу подключить Django к PostgreSQL

Tags: django, postgresql

Всем привет!
Я сразу говорю что установил саму бд и psycopg2, при команде makemigrations получаю ошибку:

```
  (venv) C:\Users\piple\PycharmProjects\books\books>python manage.py makemigrations
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\piple\PycharmProjects\books\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\piple\PycharmProjects\books\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\piple\PycharmProjects\books\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 200, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\piple\PycharmProjects\books\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\piple\PycharmProjects\books\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py", line 187, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\piple\PycharmProjects\books\venv\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 127, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\piple\PycharmProjects\books\books\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\piple\PycharmProjects\books\books\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\piple\PycharmProjects\books\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\piple\PycharmProjects\books\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\piple\PycharmProjects\books\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\piple\PycharmProjects\books\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 371, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\piple\PycharmProjects\books\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 85, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\piple\PycharmProjects\books\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\makemigrations.py", line 101, in handle
    loader.check_consistent_history(connection)
  File "C:\Users\piple\PycharmProjects\books\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 290, in check_consistent_history
    applied = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "C:\Users\piple\PycharmProjects\books\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 77, in applied_migrations
    if self.has_table():
  File "C:\Users\piple\PycharmProjects\books\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 55, in has_table
    with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
  File "C:\Users\piple\PycharmProjects\books\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\piple\PycharmProjects\books\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 259, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "C:\Users\piple\PycharmProjects\books\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 235, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "C:\Users\piple\PycharmProjects\books\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\piple\PycharmProjects\books\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\piple\PycharmProjects\books\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\piple\PycharmProjects\books\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\piple\PycharmProjects\books\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\piple\PycharmProjects\books\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 200, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\piple\PycharmProjects\books\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\piple\PycharmProjects\books\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py", line 187, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\piple\PycharmProjects\books\venv\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 127, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
django.db.utils.OperationalError
```

Comment: Возможно `postgresql` не запущена, попробуйте ввести команду `service postgresql status` и посмотреть что там в `Active`.

Comment: а куда эту команду вводить просто в консоль там же где и запускать сервер ?

Comment: Да, просто в терминал.

Answer (score 0):

Просто нужно было такие же данные вести что в settings.py и что в самом pgAdmin